# Cleanup tags from json prior to writing to Excel

Tags: python, json, excel, tags

I receive a json dataset from external so I cannot influence the format. The data values are formatted with square brackets and double quotes. For example, [{ "casenumber":["12345678"],"problemcode":["ABC123"],"TITLE":["Are You Kidding Me?"] }]

I am able to read/parse this into a DataFrame, but when I try to write the DataFrame to Excel all of the data are tagged with square brackets and single quotes. Is there a way I can remove all the tags so that I don't then need to manually cleanup the Excel data?

I have tried a few variations on post-processing the data after reading it from JSON, but I can't quite get it to work

```
import json, 
def getJSONData(file):
    returnFrame = pd.DataFrame()
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as jsonfile:
                json_data=jsonfile.read()
                loaded_json = json.loads(json_data)

                returnFrame=returnFrame.append(loaded_json)
    #strip out tags
    for label, content in returnFrame.iteritems():
                    returnFrame[label]=content.replace("[","")
    return returnFrame
.
.
.
caseDataFrame=getJSONData(JSONFolderFileName)
caseDataFrame.to_excel('CaseData'+str(time.time())+'.xlsx')
```

In excel the data look like(imagine the "|" is the cell border):

casenumber  |   problemcode   |  TITLE

['12345678'] |  ['ABC123']   |   ['Are You Kidding Me?']

and I would rather it look like:

casenumber  |   problemcode  |   TITLE

12345678   |    ABC123     |     Are You Kidding Me?

Comment: I would have thought that those were arrays, containing a single element, so I doubt that attempting to replace the characters [ ] would help.I think you will have to *flatten* them. That is, assign the property to the first element of the array (for the property). Maybe `content = content[0]`.

Comment: Or `returnFrame[label] = content[0]`.

Comment: As an aside, you could use Power Query in Excel to import the JSON from a file. It seems to work OK with your sample data above.

Answer (score 0):

Provided its all in that same format, this should work:

```
data =  [{ "casenumber":["12345678"],"problemcode":["ABC123"],"TITLE":["Are You Kidding Me?"] }]


import pandas as pd

def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out



flat = flatten_json(data)

results = pd.DataFrame()
columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    row_idx = item.split('_')[0]
    column = item.split('_')[1]

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]
    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

results.to_excel('path/file.xls', index = False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
  casenumber problemcode                TITLE
0   12345678      ABC123  Are You Kidding Me?
```